# timestamp based concurrency

Tags: transaction, concurrency, timestamp

I am wondering if someone could help me out with a question I have about time stamp based concurrency.

I found the following practice problem on a website

It basically asks which of the following 4 will occur for the LAST transaction:

```
(a) the request is accepted.

(b) the request is ignored.

(c) the transaction is delayed.

(d) the transaction is rolled back.
```

The  stands for the order of the time stamps and the  = read  = write

```
st1; st2; r2(A); co2; r1(A); w1(A)
```

The solution they give is choice (d) which had me kind of confused as to how they are coming to that.  I may be mistaken about how the time stamps work but I thought that if a transaction wishes to access a shared variable it must have the earliest time stamp.  In this example transaction 2 tries to read(A) first but I thought that should be delayed (since transaction 1 has the earlier of the 2 time stamps.  So once we get to the r1(A), w1(A) since transaction 1 has the earlier stamp that should succeed as I understand it so I'm not sure why they choose (d).  If I am misunderstanding the concept could someone please explain it to me I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

"Transaction T can read or write data item X only if X had not been accessed by a "later" transaction.  Otherwise, the operation of T is rejected; T is aborted and restarted with new TS".

In other words we have:

ST1 and then ST2 any data that is read or write by T2, could not be access by T1 or it will rollback that is because T2 start after T1.

I found it [here](http://www2.cs.uh.edu/~marek/notes/lecture13/sld028.htm) in the slide 28

I hope it helped you